# Basic Multivariate Regression Analysis with R

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, prediction

I'm trying to look for simple patterns in weather data. Here's a simplified version of what I'm working with.

```
day <- c(4, 5, 6, 8)
temp <- c(97, 100, 98, 80)
humidity <- c(62, 46, 50, 55)
```

Suppose I wanted to predict the temperature on day 7 and day 9 (neither are listed) using the following factors. Which R command would I use to do this?

I know how do predictions using 2 variables.
*(updated using Greg Snow's answer)*

```
fit <- lm(temp ~ day)
newdat <- data.frame( day=c(7,9) )
predict(fit, newdat)
```

But how would I go about using more than 2?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is much easier to use the `predict` function in R.  First create a new data frame with a column named `day` with the values that you want to predict for, then pass that along with the fitted model to the `predict` function.  It is important that the new data frame has columns with the exact same names as the original variables:

```
newdat <- data.frame( day=c(7,9) )
predict(fit, newdat)
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post using the improved method. Do you know how to fit multiple variables? I would assume fit <- lm(humidity ~ temp ~ day) would work, but it doesn't. I'm fairly new to R.

Comment: See `?formula` for the details on how to specify the formulas for various linear models.  The short is that you would use `lm( humidity~temp+day)` or `lm(humidity~humidity*day)` depending on whether you want an interaction or not.

Comment: I should have known that... Thank you for your time and help.